# Using Multiprocessing module for updating Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have been trying to use Multiprocessing module for updating Tkinter GUI but when I run this code, it is giving Pickling error.

```
# Test Code for Tkinter with threads
import Tkinter
from multiprocessing import Queue
import multiprocessing
import time

# Data Generator which will generate Data
def GenerateData():
    global q
    for i in range(10):
        print "Generating Some Data, Iteration %s" %(i)
        time.sleep(2)
        q.put("Some Data from iteration %s \n" %(i))

def QueueHandler():
    global q, text_wid
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            str = q.get()
            text_wid.insert("end", str)

# Main Tkinter Application
def GUI():
    global text_wid
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    text_wid = Tkinter.Text(tk)
    text_wid.pack()
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Queue which will be used for storing Data
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    text_wid = Tkinter.Text(tk)
    q = multiprocessing .Queue()
    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,))
    t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=QueueHandler,args=(q,text_wid))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    text_wid.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
```

If I remove the argument `text_wid`, then no error is reported but text widget is not updated with the data from the queque.

**UPDATE :**

I modified code so as to call the function to update the GUI whenever there is value in queue, thus preventing Tkinter widgets from being passed to separate process. Now, I am not getting any error but the widget is not updated with the data. However if i use mix of `Threading` and `Multiprocessing` module i.e. create a separate thread for handling data from the queue, then it works fine. My question why didn't it worked when i run the handler code in separate process. Am I not passing the data correctly. Below is the modified code:

```
# Test Code for Tkinter with threads
import Tkinter
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time
import threading

# Data Generator which will generate Data
def GenerateData(q):
    for i in range(10):
        print "Generating Some Data, Iteration %s" %(i)
        time.sleep(2)
        q.put("Some Data from iteration %s \n" %(i))

def QueueHandler(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            str = q.get()
            update_gui(str)
            #text_wid.insert("end", str)

# Main Tkinter Application
def GUI():
    global text_wid
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    text_wid = Tkinter.Text(tk)
    text_wid.pack()
    tk.mainloop()

def update_gui(str):
    global text_wid
    text_wid.insert("end", str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Queue which will be used for storing Data
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    text_wid = Tkinter.Text(tk)
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,))
    t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=QueueHandler,args=(q,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    text_wid.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `tkinter` functions from threads/processes other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk()` window. `tkinter` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

You missed out an important part, you should protect your calls with a `__main__` trap:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    q = Queue.Queue()
    # Create a thread and run GUI & QueueHadnler in it
    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,))
    t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=QueueHandler,args=(q,))

    ....
```

Note that the Queue is passed as a parameter rather than using a global.

Edit:  just spotted another issue, you should be using `Queue` from the `multiprocessing` module, not from `Queue`:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Comment: I modified the code as suggested and now I am getting the Pickling error (Error that I am getting in my original application code) PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock

Comment: Have you moved the Queue object out of global space?  Probably a good idea to pass `text_wid` as a parameter as well.  Generally, if you ever wondered why you should not use globals then doing any form of multitasking will show you good reasons!

Comment: Yes, I moved queue object out of global space and passing through arguments. I tried passing "text_wid" as argument but didn't  helped. I will be posting modified code.

Comment: See my new edit about using Queue from the multiprocessing module, I think this is where your pickle issue is.

Comment: Now it is giving error for TkApp module. `PicklingError: Can't pickle 'tkapp' object: <tkapp object at 0x02906AD8>`. Any substitute for it as well?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with Tk.  I guess the error message says it all, and it looks like Tk can't be used with multiprocessing.  This is not unreasonable, graphic displays are not normally shared between processes.

Comment: If, I remove the `text_wid` as argument, then no error is reported. But data is not shown in widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Test Code for Tkinter with threads
import Tkinter as Tk
import multiprocessing
from Queue import Empty, Full
import time

class GuiApp(object):
   def __init__(self,q):
      self.root = Tk.Tk()
      self.root.geometry('300x100')
      self.text_wid = Tk.Text(self.root,height=100,width=100)
      self.text_wid.pack(expand=1,fill=Tk.BOTH)
      self.root.after(100,self.CheckQueuePoll,q)

   def CheckQueuePoll(self,c_queue):
      try:
         str = c_queue.get(0)
         self.text_wid.insert('end',str)
      except Empty:
         pass
      finally:
         self.root.after(100, self.CheckQueuePoll, c_queue)

# Data Generator which will generate Data
def GenerateData(q):
   for i in range(10):
      print "Generating Some Data, Iteration %s" %(i)
      time.sleep(2)
      q.put("Some Data from iteration %s \n" %(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
# Queue which will be used for storing Data

   q = multiprocessing.Queue()
   q.cancel_join_thread() # or else thread that puts data will not term
   gui = GuiApp(q)
   t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,))
   t1.start()
   gui.root.mainloop()

   t1.join()
   t2.join()
```

Comment: This answer would be considerably more useful if you gave at least a little description of your solution. What lines did you change, add, or remove, and why?

Comment: Agreed, some comments would probable be beneficial to the community. The solution works very well, though. I have @user2464430 's example here for a similar problem and it's working like a charm.

I will note that for a proper start of the multiprocessing thread on windows I had to add `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` immediately after the __main__ instantiation or I got an error and no start of this thread.