# Matplotlib, Tkinter, Serial Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing

I created a code (using Tkinter, Python3 and matplotlid) that could read data from different serial ports, save them to csv, then create graphs and finally preview data in GUI. The code was splited in two different scripts. The main script contained reading data, save data to csv an priview of data and the other script contained the graph creation.

Today I rewrote the code using the answer of @user2464430 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228763/using-multiprocessing-module-for-updating-tkinter-gui). The code is working, but I can't update the GUI. Opens once and then no refresh with new data.

The following code is a part of total code.

My code is:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import tkinter as Tk
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty, Full
from time import strftime

import serial
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

import locale

import os


class GuiApp(object):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.root = Tk.Tk()
        self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")

        C = Canvas(self.root, bg="black", width=1600, height=800)

        def BasicLabels():
              ....... # in this stage create multiple axis labels 

            ΥAxisLabels()

        BasicLabels()

        def ValueLabels():

            ....... # Read and munipulate datas from CSV file and print in in labels
            
        ValueLabels()

        C.pack()


def GenerateData(q): #Read Serial Ports and store data to CSV file
    file_exists = os.path.isfile("BigData.csv")

    header = [["Daytime,T1"]]

    if not file_exists:
        with open("BigData.csv", "a+") as csvfile:
            np.savetxt(csvfile, header, delimiter=",", fmt="%s", comments="")

    while True:
        try:
            ser1 = serial.Serial(port="COM4", baudrate=9600)
            read_ser1 = ser1.readline()
            if read_ser1 == "":
                read_ser1 = "Missing Value"
            else:
                read_ser1 = ser1.readline()
                read_ser1 = str(read_ser1[0 : len(read_ser1)].decode("utf-8"))
                # print("COM4:", read_ser1)
            ser1.close()
        except:
            print("Failed 1")
            read_ser1 = "9999,9999,9999,9999,9999"

        daytime = strftime(" %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

        rows = [
            daytime
            + ","
            + read_ser1.strip()
        ]
        with open("BigData.csv", "a+") as csvfile:
            np.savetxt(csvfile, rows, delimiter=",", fmt="%s", comments="")

        CreateGraphs()
      
def CreateGraphs():
    #Code to generate graph. Called every time i have new line in CSV.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Queue which will be used for storing Data

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q.cancel_join_thread()  # or else thread that puts data will not term
    gui = GuiApp(q)

    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData, args=(q,))
    t1.start()

    gui.root.mainloop()

    t1.join()
```

The graphs are generating after while True in `GenerateData`.

All datas for labels and graphs are coming from CSV file and not directly from serial port.

Is it possible to update GUI with latest datas from CSV and created graphs?

Thank for your time.

Comment: That is way too much code for us to look through. Please give us a [mre].

Comment: @TheLizzard I'll try to post less code. Thanks.